# Is it possible to make certain disk sectors readonly

Tags: usb, read-only, partitioning, sectors

Is it by anyway possible to make certain disk sectors read-only? (The disk being specifically a **USB Flash drive**). Also the possibility of repartitioning the drive and making one partition read-only would also be great.

Comment: What's the make and model of the flashdrive? There are utilities for different brands that let you partition and format them with advanced options.

Comment: It's a Transcend.

Answer (score 1):

You could give this utility a try: http://agnipulse.com/2011/11/partition-usb-flash-drive/

If that doesn't work you could look for a utility tailored to your make and model drive, but after a bit of research there doesn't seem to be anything special about yours. (Besides the partition *removal* software the company offers)